# How to use web-mode to edit multiline HTML inside backticks?

Tags: web-mode

I often work with Angular and Typescript, and I'm fond of putting my Angular templates directly into my Typescript files. The resulting code is essentially Javascript with HTML snippets in it, like this:

```
showModal() {
  return modalService.open({
    template: `
<div>
    <h1 class="some-class"
        ng-click="some-method">A heading</h1>
</div>
`,
    controller: ...
  });
}
```

I would love if `web-mode` could detect the HTML section and apply HTML syntax highlighting and indentation rules. But unfortunately, `web-mode` seems to treat everything inside the backticks as a simple string, so it doesn't work.

Back when I used to work with Coffeescript this sort of thing worked fine, but Coffeescript used a different delimiter for multiline strings (triple double-quotes I think).

Is there some way to configure `web-mode` to do the right thing here?

Answer (score 1):

The version 14.1.16 of web-mode available on github provides this feature : https://github.com/fxbois/web-mode

Comment: You could make your answer more usefull by naming the version (it won't be the last some day) as well as providing a link.

Comment: Thanks @fxbois! I just tried out version 14.1.18 from github. It doesn't seem to be working perfectly: the indentation is slightly improved (?) but there is no syntax highlighting--the whole HTML snippet is just colored like a string. Tag auto-closing doesn't work either. Am I missing something?